# cat not working a pipe

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

#### Revised version of question:

```
cat - | tr "a-z" "A-Z" | tr "A-Z" "a-z"
```

does not give any output when I run it on my bash shell prompt. I have to press Ctrl-D to get the o/p.

o/p

```
$ cat - | tr "a-z" "A-Z" | tr "A-Z" "a-z"
this is a test
```

However this works just fine and I get the output without using Ctrl-D..Why ?

```
cat - | tr "a-z" "A-Z"
```

o/p

```
$ cat - | tr "a-z" "A-Z" 
this is a test
THIS IS A TEST
```

---

#### Original version of question:

```
cat "$@" | tr "a-z" "A-Z" | tr "A-Z" "a-z"
```

hangs when I run it on my bash shell prompt. Why is that?

My `$@` is empty.

However this works like this

```
cat "$@" | tr "a-z" "A-Z"
```

Comment: After your edit to remove references to "$@", the question now doesn't make sense. Using "-", both forms are equivalent and behave the same way as far as blocking goes. I think you should restore the previous version.

Comment: I made more changes, now I am showing the o/p also.

Comment: @Idelic both forms are not equivalent. Thats what I am trying to point out.

Comment: As you wrote them at the time I wrote the comment, they were equivalent in terms of blocking, not in terms of the output: both forms (with `cat -`) will block until you hit Ctrl-D. If you use `cat "$@"`, they are not equivalent in terms of needing Ctrl-D (they behave differently if $@ is empty or not). Your last edit makes things a bit clearer, and I answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is due to buffering. In

```
cat - | tr a-z A-Z | tr A-Z a-z
```

(no quotes needed) you may not get the output immediately after you hit
ENTER, because the middle or third `tr` may have buffered the data
internally.  At some point, they will flush their buffers and you'll get
the full, correct output. Hitting Ctrl-D closes the pipe and forces a flush.

This is a fairly typical phenomenon when connecting several commands in one
pipe.

By the way, in *this* case (but not when using "$@"), the `cat -` is superfluous.

Comment: Yes I verified that by entering large amounts of text ( as an i/p to cat) I do get an output with the two pipe construct above. This is the answer I was looking for ! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If `$@` is empty, `cat` will wait for input on stdin, which is bound to your tty when you run it from a shell prompt.  Type ctrl-D (to indicate end of file), and you'll be back at your prompt.

In a script, `$@` will probably expand to a filename, so the behavior is different.